# Call a Controller Function Directly from view button

Tags: laravel-5

**Problem** I want to call My controller function from my blade button and I face some errors.

> (ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 603: Action
>   App\Http\Controllers\OrderController@Orderfun not defined. (View:
>   C:\Users\MalikTariq\Project\resources\views\admin.blade.php))

My controller function is:

```
     public function Orderfun(){
        // $data=Orders::all();
        // foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        //     echo "value is =".$value;
        echo "My name is Malik ";
                           }
```

Route is:

```
Route::get('Order/Orderfun', 'AdminController@Orderfun');
```

My blade code is:

```
<a href="{{action('OrderController@Orderfun')}}"><button type="button"      class="btn btn-danger" id="bt1">View Orders</button></a>
```

Comment: https://advancedwebtuts.com/tutorial/how-to-call-a-controller-function-on-button-click-in-laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use route method instead of action method in href attribute of a element in your view.

Comment: After use Route method :  ErrorException in UrlGenerator.php line 307:
Route [OrderController@Orderfun] not defined. (View: C:\Users\MalikTariq\Project\resources\views\admin.blade.php)

Comment: Or you can directly use the url as <a href="/Order/Orderfun">view orders<a>